# Query to find the database objects size oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

I have requirement to get to "Find out the amount of data ingested/loaded on a daily basis interms of size in GB"

so the options  1) i have to look at the auditing table in order to find the over all data processed on a daily basis

2. is it necessary for me to check some of the key dba tables/objects as well ?

dba_segments
dba_indexes
dba_lobs

so my ask over here is in order to get the size of the overall

Option 1 - check the audit table , how to capture the size in GB ?
Option 2 - please see the query

query (option 2)

```
SELECT
   owner, 
   table_name, 
   TRUNC(sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024) GB,
   ROUND( ratio_to_report( sum(bytes) ) over () * 100) Percent
FROM
(SELECT segment_name table_name, owner, bytes
 FROM dba_segments
 WHERE segment_type IN ('TABLE', 'TABLE PARTITION', 'TABLE SUBPARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT i.table_name, i.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_indexes i, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = i.index_name
 AND   s.owner = i.owner
 AND   s.segment_type IN ('INDEX', 'INDEX PARTITION', 'INDEX SUBPARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.segment_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type IN ('LOBSEGMENT', 'LOB PARTITION')
 UNION ALL
 SELECT l.table_name, l.owner, s.bytes
 FROM dba_lobs l, dba_segments s
 WHERE s.segment_name = l.index_name
 AND   s.owner = l.owner
 AND   s.segment_type = 'LOBINDEX')
--WHERE owner in UPPER()
GROUP BY table_name, owner
--HAVING SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 > 10  /* Ignore really small tables */
ORDER BY SUM(bytes) desc;
```

any betters ways to check ?

Comment: IDK if there is a system table/view that shows a history of that.  You may have to obtain the current sizes, then store that in a table with date and size?

Comment: It depends on what it is you really want to measure.  Adding a single row of 128 bytes _could potentially_ cause a new extent (of multiple 8k blocks) to be allocated, which in turn could cause a file to have to auto-extend by some amount. Are you interested in the 128 bytes of data, or the increased size of the table segment (and potentially any indexes as well) or the size of the data files?

Comment: Also consider that the insert transactions will generate redo log entries in addition to the data that actually goes into the tables and indexes, that will need to be archived and backed up. Are you interested in that storage as well?